# How can I select which files to show warnings for?

Tags: ruby, warnings, suppress-warnings

To show warnings with Ruby one can call `ruby` with the flag `-w`. When using libraries Ruby may show lots of warnings so that it is hard to find the warnings from the files you are actually working on. Is it possible to tell `ruby` to show warnings for some files only?

Here is an example to illustrate the problem. The following loads a library that generates lots of warnings and it also produces a warning on its own by redefining a constant.

```
require 'grooveshark'

CONSTANT = 'foo'
CONSTANT = 'bar'
```

The output of `ruby -w warning_test.rb` is as follows:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/exceptions.rb:157: warning: assigned but unused variable - message
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/exceptions.rb:167: warning: assigned but unused variable - message
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/response.rb:11: warning: method redefined; discarding old body
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:47: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'case' at 40
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/macaddr-1.6.1/lib/macaddr.rb:63: warning: assigned but unused variable - status
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/macaddr-1.6.1/lib/macaddr.rb:63: warning: assigned but unused variable - stderr
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/macaddr-1.6.1/lib/macaddr.rb:56: warning: assigned but unused variable - re
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/macaddr-1.6.1/lib/macaddr.rb:59: warning: assigned but unused variable - null
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:126: warning: shadowing outer local variable - cid
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:213: warning: shadowing outer local variable - buf
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:215: warning: shadowing outer local variable - buf
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:208: warning: assigned but unused variable - ignored
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:252: warning: shadowing outer local variable - key
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.5.2/lib/systemu.rb:249: warning: assigned but unused variable - ignored
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grooveshark-0.2.7/lib/grooveshark/user.rb:65: warning: method redefined; discarding old playlists
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grooveshark-0.2.7/lib/grooveshark/user.rb:93: warning: method redefined; discarding old favorites
warning_test.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant CONSTANT
```

In this case I would only like to see only the last warning

```
warning_test.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant CONSTANT
```

Since the other warnings are due to libraries I do not have direct control over the warnings for them are not as interesting. I would like to be able to tell Ruby to only show warnings for the project one is working.

I realize that defining the current might be tricky. Maybe to only show warnings for the given file and files included via `require_relative` would do. Another alternative is to show warnings for files that are close in the directory structure to the given file.

Comment: What kind of warning are you talking about?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: exceptions, maybe?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I am referring to those you get when you use `-w` with `ruby`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not exceptions, check my update.

Comment: @user2060534 The files in the same package or only those files included by `require_relative`?

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect stderr to stdout and then grep. Here's an example:

`ruby -w warning_test.rb 2>&1 | grep "warning_test"`

Comment: Another alternative is to grep out the libraries, using `grep -v gems`.